# Springers svmult template cannot generate bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, sv-classes

No bibliographic reference is generated. Tried to compile with both bibtex and biber, with no result in either of them. The package may be downloaded from [Springers svmult template](http://www.csikolkata.org/human2024/contributed-books.zip). I have used the content under Author folder.

```
\documentclass[graybox]{svmult}
\usepackage{type1cm}        
%\usepackage{makeidx}         % allows index generation
\usepackage{graphicx}        % standard LaTeX graphics tool
                             % when including figure files
\usepackage{multicol}        % used for the two-column index
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom
\usepackage{newtxtext}       %
\usepackage[varvw]{newtxmath}       % selects Times Roman as basic font
%\makeindex             % used for the subject index
                       % please use the style svind.ist with
                       % your makeindex program
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}
\usepackage{amsmath, mathtools}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage[center]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
%\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}%
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%Table packages
%Packages for Rotatebox
\usepackage[graphicx]{realboxes}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\footnotesize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{3pt}  % <--- new
\usepackage{siunitx}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength {\marginparwidth }{2cm}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\title*{My title}
\author{The authors}
\maketitle
\abstract{Some abstract.
}
\keywords{Internet of Things(IoT), Machine Learning, AI, Electronic Health Record}

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:1}
Some text \cite{moses2021application}.

\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

I have the following two references in references.bib file that are appearing as list during \cite{} in overlief but the Reference is not produced after the document.
The content of references.bib

```
@article{khan2022iot,
  title={IoT-based health monitoring system development and analysis},
  author={Khan, Mohammad Monirujjaman and Alanazi, Turki M and Albraikan, Amani Abdulrahman and Almalki, Faris A and others},
  journal={Security and Communication Networks},
  volume={2022},
  year={2022},
  publisher={Hindawi}
}

@inproceedings{moses2021application,
  title={Application of smartphone technologies in disease monitoring: a systematic review},
  author={Moses, Jeban Chandir and Adibi, Sasan and Shariful Islam, Sheikh Mohammed and Wickramasinghe, Nilmini and Nguyen, Lemai},
  booktitle={Healthcare},
  volume={9},
  number={7},
  pages={889},
  year={2021},
  organization={MDPI}
}
```

All the style files are under the root. Including them (one at a time) using the \bibliographystyle{stylename} did not help either.

Comment: You need `\bibliographystyle{<something>>}` where `<something>` is one of `spbasic`, `spsmpsci`, `spphys`, `svind` or `svindd`. Take your pick.

Comment: Tried with all bib styles available inside the folder already ☹️

Comment: At last found out that their supplied reference file is not a bib file, but rather a tex file. Creating a fresh bib file with the above two references solved the problem.

Comment: @Bukaida, I suggest to put your comment as an answer (=solution) to your question. It's more prominent this way, and perhaps you can add, what wouldn't fit inside a comment.

Comment: Can't answer own question within 48 hours, forum policy. However, it is likely that some other beginner like me can save time in future through this clue. So, will mark it as helpful when the cooling period is over.